# Как не выйти за рамки шахматной доски?

Tags: java, строки, методы, char

Решаю задачку про коня на шахматной доске. Цель задачи - узнать, может ли конь совершить ход в прописанную клетку или нет.

Сам код рабочий, хоть пока еще не красивый (скидывать не буду), но осталась проблема в границах поля. На данный момент компилятор выдает `false`, если конь пошел на клетку, номер которой больше 8.

Но нужно еще сделать так, чтобы на выходе был `false`, если клетка не будет находиться в диапазоне букв `a-h`. Например, когда я пишу `h1-i3` (текущая клетка и следующая), - то программа считает, что такой ход возможен, потому что конь пошел буквой Г, но не учитывает, что `i` находится за пределами поля.

Если же прописать, например, `a8-b10`, то здесь программа понимает, что вышли за пределы.

Вопрос, как ограничить символы, также как и цифры? Делаю этот кусок кода таким образом:

```
return ((horizontal < 'a'|| horizontal  > 'h')||  (vertical < 1 || vertical > 8));
```

Может кто-то подскажет?

Answer (score 2):

Вроде бы у вас сравнение char-ов должно работать. У меня получилось так:

```
private static boolean isLegalChessMove(String move) {
    if (move.length() != 2) {
        return false;
    }
    char horizontal = move.charAt(0);
    char vertical = move.charAt(1);

    return isSymbolBetween(horizontal, 'a', 'h') &&
           isSymbolBetween(vertical, '1', '8');
}

private static boolean isSymbolBetween(char symbol, char firstBorder, char secondBorder) {
    return symbol >= firstBorder && symbol <= secondBorder;
}
```

Comment: Спасибо! Посмотрю, как получится у меня.

Comment: Нашел свою ошибку, благодаря Вашему коду. Между блоками операторы перепутал. Еще раз спасибо.